# XSD change the available elements based on a previous Element Value

Tags: xsd

Is there a way to change the available elements based on a previous element value?

I have some lookup 'Cause' codes but some of these only belong to certain 'Products'.

I therefore want to create each products lookup cause code enumeration and let this only be available based on the product selection.

Is this possible ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think those sort of "business rules" can be expressed in XSD.

One option is to also create [schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) validation rules to enforce those sort of conditional structure rules based upon element/attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

You can effect element polymorphism (of the same name) in the XSD for instance elements decorated w/ enumerated xsi:type attributes as described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188389/xml-schema-for-elements-with-same-name-but-different-sub-structure-depending-on#233093)