# How to design xsd schema for two common elements with different input data?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I need an advice how to design **xsd schema** to represent objects.

I have a such interface

```
public interface Validator{
     boolean validate(Q query);   
}
```

And I have some implementations -

```
public class SimpleValidator implements Validator{

     private R param;

     public boolean validate(Q Query){
          //some logic with using param   
     }

     public void setParam(R param){
         this.param = param;
     }
}


public class AnotherValidator implements Validator{

     private Data data1;
     private Data data1;

     public boolean validate(Q Query){
          //some logic with using data1 and data2   
     }

     public void setData1(Data data1){
         this.data1 = data1;
     }

     public void setData2(Data data2){
         this.data2 = data2;
     }
}
```

I have such decision -

I create root element - `<xsd:element name="validator" type="validatorType"/>`

And such elements -

```
<xsd:element name="simpleValidator" type="simpleValidatorType"  substitutionGroup="validator"/>

<xsd:element name="anotherValidator" type="anotherValidatorType"  substitutionGroup="validator"/>
```

Now I can use tags `simpleValidator` and `anotherValidator` in the place where is needing `validator`. Example -

```
<anotherValidator>
     <data1 value="value1"/>
     <data2 value="value2"/>
</anotherValidator>
```

The problem is, that I want to use only tag `validator`. As example, I want something like this -

```
<validator type="simpleValidator>
     //simpleValidator data
</validator>

<validator type="anotherValidator>
     //anotherValidator data
</validator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done using [Runtime Polymorphism via xsi:type and Abstract Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468563.aspx#xmlschmachng_topic04)
I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188389/xml-schema-for-elements-with-same-name-but-different-sub-structure-depending-on) also : May be helpful.

In one of my project i was dellign with  , but there are different type of address namely shippingAddress, billingAddress ..we used this techniqe to solve our problem.

Comment: Interesting information! Thanks! I'll read it and try, then write you how it works for me.

Comment: WOW! It works good! May be you know a way, to change attribute name "xsi:type" to attribute "type"? My schema will be look perfect

Comment: If your know answer, you can answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378431/how-to-rename-attribute-xsitype-to-type

Comment: ok i will try to look it tonight , my timezoen is GMT+6 , need to catch my bus